# Regular expression in extjs for a phone number

Tags: regex, extjs

I want to build vtype for the US Phone number like ( 408) 898-8979 or ( 408) 898-8589-8989.

The regular expression must accept any of the format.

I tried so many samples.

Comment: what you have tried so far. show us the code

Comment: read this : https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask **and** http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

What's with the spaces in `( xxx)`?

```
Ext.form.VTypes["usPhoneNumber"] = /\(\ *[0-9]{3}\ *\)\ *[2-9]\d{2}-\d{4}(-\d{4})?$/
```

[Check this site](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?categoryId=7&cattabindex=6&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 0):

POSIX format:

```
[\(]408[\)][[:digit:]]\{3\}-\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)\{1,2\}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a regex like this: `^\( *\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}(-\d{4})?$`.